# Mathematics on a special column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do a mathematic on a column of my table.
i have numbers in my column that i want to divide by 11  and then *0.5 and mines from frist number can i do somthing like this with only mysql? or need to a php file to do this ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT numcol, ((numcol / 11 ) * 0.5 - numcol) AS calccol
  FROM special_table;
```

Comment: but in the end i wanna mines this from frist number fro example:

Comment: (x/11)*0.5-x         x is the value of that column

Comment: @babakfaghihian, I've updated my answer. Just do the needed calculations, it's not a big deal adding extra math operations.

Comment: i see tanx its compelet but what is calccol?

Comment: @babakfaghihian, it is just an alias for the column. You can use `x` there if you want to.

Comment: tanx my friend you helped me so much

Answer (score 0):

Better will be that you leave the calculation logic in your application layer rather than in your database layer, but if you still want Try this :

```
Select ((column/11)*0.5) from mytable
```